# Paypal API 'Timeout processing request' error

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am facing 'Timeout processing request' error while using Paypal Sandbox

I used 'SetExpressCheckout' and it works fine but when I used the recieved token for processing 'CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile', I get timeout error.

I have created custom class but code overall is similar to the code at this page https://www.x.com/paypal-apis-createrecurringpaymentsprofile-php-5.3/nvp

Comment: this is what i get...

`Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [L_ERRORCODE] => 10001
            [L_SHORTMESSAGE] => Internal%20Error
            [L_LONGMESSAGE] => Timeout%20processing%20request
            [L_SEVERITYCODE] => 
        )

)`

Comment: Please include the full API request for both API calls.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem before. If it's the same issue I am thinking of, it's because Payal sometimes messes up within the Cookies of the browser you are using. Try it in another browser for testing, it totally clear your cache and then try again. If it's the same issue I am thinking of, then that should fix it.